# parse express app.js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to get a list of all available routes based on the all.js file.?

Answer (score 2):

You can dig around inside the `app.routes` object, which is an instance of `Router`.  The easiest way would probably be to load up your app in an interactive listener and just take a look at the various objects contained in `app.routes`.

If you want to be more methodical, you can read the source for the router and route objects, e.g. https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing when you typed this answer.  I've posted it seperately, but the OP should do what you suggested in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a better way of doing this, TJ Holowaychuck (the author of Express) made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1288766) with it:

```
app.routes.all().forEach(function(route){
  console.log('  \033[90m%s \033[36m%s\033[0m', route.method.toUpperCase(), route.path);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, at least not for me. Using express 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var type in app.routes.routes) {
  console.log(type+":");
  for(var rts in app.routes.routes[type]) {
    console.log(app.routes.routes[type][rts]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The routes object has verbs as properties. You can iterate over them and construct a list of all routes, methods etc.

I created a Gist creating a self describing rest-api. I'm sure it can be improved but if you want you can see how I iterate over the routes object there.

https://gist.github.com/morkeleb/5705647

Feedback is welcome on the Gist.